# How to find the intersecting point in the regression line

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

In the above graph two vertical and horizontal line segments are drawn which will intersect the regression line. How to write code to draw those lines to find the intersecting point?

Comment: Please provide example input data, and code you have tried so far.

Comment: Use a functione like `coef()` to extract the coefficients from your linear model. Using these you can simply solve your equations.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you think that Allan has answered your question, kindly consider accepting it by ticking the check mark next to his answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula for each regression line is printed on the plot, so we can get the information by simple algebra.

First we will plot each regression line:

```
x   <- c(0, 22)
y0  <- 27.46 + 0.31 * x
y5  <- 40.18 + 0.49 * x
y10 <- 55.54 + 0.67 * x
y15 <- 71.63 + 0.84 * x

plot(x, y0, type = "l", ylim = c(0, 105), xlim = c(0, 25),
     ylab = "Percentage of VO2max", xlab = "Load (kg)")
lines(x, y5)
lines(x, y10)
lines(x, y15)
```

[image]

Now we just rearrange the appropriate regression line formulas with y = 50, y = 60, and y = 75:

```
x5  <- (50 - 40.18) / 0.49
x10 <- (60 - 55.54) / 0.67
x15 <- (75 - 71.63) / 0.84
```

So we can add these to our plot to show that we have the intersections:

```
abline(h = 50, lty = 2, col = "red")
abline(h = 60, lty = 2, col = "blue")
abline(h = 75, lty = 2, col = "green")
lines(c(x5, x5), c(50, 0), lty = 2, col = "red")
lines(c(x10, x10), c(60, 0), lty = 2, col = "blue")
lines(c(x15, x15), c(75, 0), lty = 2, col = "green")
points(c(x5, x10, x15), c(50, 60, 75))
```

[image]

This looks good. So our three intersections are:

```
data.frame(x = c(x5, x10, x15), y = c(50, 60, 75))
          x  y
1 20.040816 50
2  6.656716 60
3  4.011905 75
```

---

**EDIT**

With some data added in the comments:

```
df <- data.frame(load = rep(c(0,4.4,10.7,17,21.4), each = 4), 
                 Gradient = c(0,5,10,15), 
                 VO2max= c(28.0,41.0,56.3,71.3,28.2,41.1,57.0,
                           75.0,31.0,45.4,63.6,82.1, 32.0,48.8,
                           66.8,85.5,34.6,50.5,69.9,89.3))

df$Gradient <- as.factor(df$Gradient)
```

It is possible to do this in ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(load, VO2max, group = Gradient)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = Gradient), size = 3) + 
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 0.31, intercept = 27.46)) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 0.49, intercept = 40.18)) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 0.67, intercept = 55.54)) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 0.84, intercept = 71.63)) +
  geom_segment(data = data.frame(x = c(x5, x10, x15),
                                 y = c(50, 60, 75),
                                 Gradient = factor(c(50, 60, 75))),
               aes(x, y, xend = x, yend = 0, colour = Gradient),
               linetype = 2) +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(load = c(x5, x10, x15), 
                               VO2max = c(50, 60, 75),
                               Gradient = 1)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 105), xlim = c(0, 25),
                  expand = 0) +
  geom_hline(data = data.frame(y = c(50, 60, 75), 
                               Gradient = factor(c(50, 60, 75))),
             aes(yintercept = y, colour = Gradient), linetype = 2) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line()) +
  guides(colour = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how to plot the bulleted points in the line.                                                      
  df<- data.frame(load=rep(c(0,4.4,10.7,17,21.4), each=4),
                  Gradient=c(0,5,10,15),
                  VO2max=c(28.0,41.0,56.3,71.3,28.2,41.1,57.0,75.0,31.0,45.4,63.6,82.1,
                           32.0,48.8,66.8,85.5,34.6,50.5,69.9,89.3))

Comment: @CheraMaan I have updated the final plot with the points included. Are these the points you mean? I have already given the co-ordinates of the points in the final data frame.

Comment: Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  invalid graphics state
2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  invalid graphics state                                                                                                getting warning message like this and the coloured lines are not drawn.                      
 No, I mean the 20 bulleted points

Comment: @CheraMaan do you mean the ones that you have just added in the comments but didn't put in the actual question that I answered?

Comment: Yes,the one in the comments. I need the intersection part only because I have already plotted the points and drawn the lines using "ggplot2" so only I hven't mentioned in the question. But the code "abline" you gave is not working.

Comment: @CheraMaan you didn't say you were working in ggplot. I have now updated to include a ggplot solution. Please include this kind of information when you ask a question to avoid unnecessary work on the part of people who answer. Hopefully this solution will work for you now.

Comment: simple algebra that's almost cheating.. :) +1