# How to solve aesthetic error while running a ggplot2 code?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The multiple linear regression model is
**Load=-33.124+1.470VO2max-4.909Gradient**
I'm working in ggplot2 and tried  to draw four different regression line by varying "Gradient=0,5,10 and 15" and also drawing the line segment having at VO2max=50,60 and 75 and finding the intersection point to get the value of the Load.

```
library("ggplot2")
df<- data.frame(load=rep(c(0,4.4,10.7,17,21.4), each=4),
                Gradient=c(0,5,10,15),
                VO2max=c(28.0,41.0,56.3,71.3,28.2,41.1,57.0,75.0,31.0,45.4,63.6,82.1,
                         32.0,48.8,66.8,85.5,34.6,50.5,69.9,89.3))
df$Gradient <- as.factor(df$Gradient)
x5  <- -57.669+7.35
x10 <- -82.214+14.7
x15 <- -106.759+22.05
ggplot(df, aes(vo2max,load, group = Gradient)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = Gradient), size = 3) + 
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 1.47, intercept = -33.124)) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 1.47, intercept = -57.669)) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 1.47, intercept = -82.214)) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 1.47, intercept = -106.759)) +
  geom_segment(data = data.frame(x = c(50, 60, 75),
                                 y = c(x5, x10, x15),
                                 Gradient = factor(c(50, 60, 75))),
               aes(x, y, xend = 0, yend = y, colour = Gradient),
               linetype = 2) +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(VO2max = c(50, 60, 75),
                               load = c(x5, x10, x15),
                               Gradient = 1)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 105), ylim = c(0, 25),
                  expand = 0) +
  geom_hline(data = data.frame(x = c(50, 60, 75), 
                               Gradient = factor(c(50, 60, 75))),
             aes(yintercept = y, colour = Gradient), linetype = 2) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line()) +
  guides(colour = "none")
data.frame(x = c(50, 60, 75),y = c(x5, x10, x15))
```

By running the code I'm getting error as:
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (20): x

Help me in solving the error and getting perfect graph

Answer (score 1):

There were a few errors here. Firstly, you have not calculated the intercept points based on the regression line formulas implied by your `geom_abline` calls.

Secondly, in your initial aesthetics call, you have done `aes(vo2max`, but the variable is called `VO2max` (case sensitive).

Thirdly, in your call to `geom_hline` the data frame you created has a variable called `x` but you are setting your `yintercept` to a variable called `y` that doesn't exist. As Ian Campbell pointed out in the comments, you want a `geom_hline` here.

You seem to have made things difficult for yourself by manually reversing the axes in the plot from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62553728/how-to-find-the-intersecting-point-in-the-regression-line). You could have done this much more simply by adding `+ coord_flip()` to the previous plot.

The following revised code works:

```
x5  <- -57.669+ 1.47 * 50
x10 <- -82.214+ 1.47 * 60
x15 <- -106.759+ 1.47 * 75

ggplot(df, aes(VO2max,load, group = Gradient)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = Gradient), size = 3) + 
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 1.47, intercept = -33.124)) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 1.47, intercept = -57.669)) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 1.47, intercept = -82.214)) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 1.47, intercept = -106.759)) +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(VO2max = c(50, 60, 75),
                             load = c(x5, x10, x15),
                             Gradient = 1)) +
  geom_segment(data = data.frame(x = c(50, 60, 75),
                                 y = c(x5, x10, x15),
                                 Gradient = factor(c(50, 60, 75))),
               aes(x, y, xend = 0, yend = y, colour = Gradient),
               linetype = 2) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 105), ylim = c(0, 25),
                  expand = 0) +
  geom_vline(data = data.frame(x = c(50, 60, 75), 
                               Gradient = factor(c(50, 60, 75))),
             aes(xintercept = x, colour = Gradient), linetype = 2) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line()) +
  guides(colour = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: The values of `x` in the `geom_hline` call are too high to be for the `y` axis, I think it is intended to be `geom_vline`.

Comment: @IanCampbell the formulae for the segments was also wrong.

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense.